# Where Joomla! store fields options from extensions

Tags: joomla

i`m not understood where Joomla! CMS store data from fields options.
This code creating form in admin site and i not finded where it is value store

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="2.5.0" method="upgrade">
    <name>mod_helloworld</name>
    <creationDate>November 2010</creationDate>
    .....
    <config>
        <fields name="params">                
            <fieldset name="basic">
            </fieldset>            
            <fieldset name="advanced">
               <field name="mytextvalue" 
                      type="text" default="Some text"
                      label="Enter some text" description="" size="10" 
               />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
```

Comment: In the extension table. Please look option field in that table

Comment: In the extension table find the result for that module and look for params column, Information for module parameters are store there in form of JSON.